# syntax error 1064 Mysql ( select * from employee limit (select count(*)/2 from employee); why is this telling syntax error at starting curve bracket

Tags: mysql

```
select * 
from employee 
limit (select count(*)/2 from employee);
```

why is  this telling syntax error at curve bracket before select keyword

I am trying to select top 50% queries of given table so i am simply trying to return count of half number of rows from sub queries and then pass it as limit value

Answer (score 1):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html has detailed documentation about MySQL's `SELECT` statement including all its clauses.

It says:

> The `LIMIT` clause can be used to constrain the number of rows returned by the `SELECT` statement. `LIMIT` takes one or two numeric arguments, which must both be nonnegative integer constants, with these exceptions:
>
> - Within prepared statements, `LIMIT` parameters can be specified using `?` placeholder markers.
> - Within stored programs, `LIMIT` parameters can be specified using integer-valued routine parameters or local variables.

Expressions, including subqueries, are not a legal argument in the `LIMIT` clause.

A simple solution would be to do your task in two queries: the first to get the `COUNT()` and then use that value as a constant value in the second query that includes the `LIMIT`.

Not every task needs to be done in a single SQL statement.